# Close open tags without wrapping in <p>

Tags: python, django, lxml

I am trying to write a clean method for my form so that if a user leaves an open in-line tag, it will be closed, e.g.:

```
Here's an <b> open tag  -> Here's an <b> open tag</b>
<i>Here are two <b>open tags -> <i>Here are two <b> open tags</b></i>
```

My code to do this is:

```
def clean_custom_title(self):
    title = self.cleaned_data.get('custom_title')
    if title:
        title = lxml.etree.tostring(lxml.html.fromstring(title))
    return title
```

which comes very close to working, except that when the string does not begin with an open tag, like my first example, it wraps everything in `<p>` tags so I get

`Here's an <b> open tag  -> <p>Here's an <b> open tag</b></p>`

I can't just strip the outer tags, as they may be correct as in my second example.  I am not worried about possible input already containing `p` tags.  I could conceivably just strip them with a remove `<p>` but that seems hacky and gross.

Note, I'm stuck using lxml.  I think BS4 would be better too but it's not my call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap everything in a throwaway tag, then get the outermost elements inner contents, like so:

```
def clean_custom_title(self):
    title = self.cleaned_data.get('custom_title')
    if title:
        title = "<foo>%s</foo>"%title
        title = lxml.html.fromstring(title)
        # title = lxml.some_function(title)  # strip <foo> in a 'proper' way
        title = lxml.etree.tostring(title)
        title = title[5:-6] # This is a hack to illustrate the premise
    return title
```

Comment: This works and is the same solution we came up with--it feels so hacky to me, but I'll accept it tomorrow if no one comes up with anything more elegant.

Comment: There is probably a more correct way to extract the inner value of `<foo>` using Xpath and stuff, but this is probably the best way.